# system.webserver section in machine.config

Tags: configuration, iis-7

I've installed Windows 2008 Web Server and enabled IIS. However, my machine.config file shows:
section name = "system.webServer" type = "System.Configuration.IgnoreSection...

Does it mean that the system.webServer section is ignored? Why?

I tried to edit some web site's properties (e.g. directory browsing), and it works correctly. Is the machine.config definition changed somewhere else?

ulu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system.webserver config is now maintained at system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config. Here's the whole new [config setup for IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/127/deep-dive-into-iis-7-configuration/).

Generally, the applicationhost.config and machine.config are for the System Admins, while the web.config is for the developer.

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this issue on and off for 6 months and this did the trick. Thanks so much!