# Where is the base IIS 7 web.config for accessing system.webServer and how do you edit it through code

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, httpmodule

I am looking to add an HttpModule to all sites on a web server. For sites not running in pipeline mode this is easy as you place your module in the base web.config.

As IIS 7 pipeline ASP.Net applications use the system.webServer section of the web.config and this doesn't appear to be in the base web.config file, where does this global change go?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine in *machine.config*, take a look at this other entry:

[system.webserver section in machine.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939737/system-webserver-section-in-machine-config)